# How to use HAL delay to generate another frequency

Tags: function, assembly, stm32, microcontroller

The code show that both reading and printing of accelerometer and temperature sensor are done every one second. But I need to read and print temperature value once every 1.5 seconds which is different from accelerometer

int main(void)
{
initialise_monitor_handles();

```
HAL_Init();


BSP_ACCELERO_Init();
BSP_TSENSOR_Init();

while (1)
{
    float accel_data[3];
    int16_t accel_data_i16[3] = { 0 };          // array to store the x, y and z readings.
    BSP_ACCELERO_AccGetXYZ(accel_data_i16);     // read accelerometer
    // the function above returns 16 bit integers which are 100 * acceleration_in_m/s2. Converting to float to print the actual acceleration.
    accel_data[0] = (float)accel_data_i16[0] / 100.0f;
    accel_data[1] = (float)accel_data_i16[1] / 100.0f;
    accel_data[2] = (float)accel_data_i16[2] / 100.0f;

    float temp_data;
    temp_data = BSP_TSENSOR_ReadTemp();         // read temperature sensor

    printf("Accel X : %f; Accel Y : %f; Accel Z : %f; Temperature : %f\n", accel_data[0], accel_data[1], accel_data[2], temp_data);

    HAL_Delay(1000);    // read once a ~second.

}
```

}

Comment: See [Multi-Rate Main Loop Tasking](https://betterembsw.blogspot.com/2015/12/multi-rate-main-loop-tasking.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here's a simple one:

```
uint32_t tick = 0u;
while (1)
{
    if ((tick % 2u) == 0u)
    {
        // Do accelerometer stuff
    }

    if ((tick % 3u) == 0u)
    {
        // Do temperature stuff
    }

    ++tick;
    HAL_Delay(500u); // Half a second
}
```

The modulo 3 is a bick icky, but you get the idea. You could have two tickers and wrap them, instead of using modulo arithmetic.

Comment: A separate down-counter (`if(--tick3){ tick3 = 3; // do temp stuff; }` might be a bit more efficient, but if your CPU has an efficient multiply instruction then ARM GCC can test for divisibility by 3 with just `mla`/`cmp` (with 2 other 32-bit constants already in other registers).  https://godbolt.org/z/eTsTTqbbE .  If your CPU doesn't have a fast multiplier, though, that's quite slow.  But still trivial if running once every half a second.

Comment: Presumably you'd want to set up a timer that fires every half second, rather than waiting until after doing the temp and/or accelerometer stuff before starting another half-second interval.  (If it's remotely possible that the old work could still be running when a timer interrupt handler fired, I guess you'd want to set flags to indicate whether you're still doing work; a pretty common problem for managing multiple timed events that aren't always synchronous.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Agreed a timer is better if you had a real requirement to be accurate. Given that the OP is already using HAL_Delay() (and printf!) I guessed they were not that bothered and just wanted to get the cadence correct.